# Whether multiple Instance of FirebaseMessagingService are Created to Handle Multiple Message?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

They are all similar questions:

1. If two FCM messages are received simultaneously on android application will `onMessageReceived()` triggered for both message simultaneously?
2. Whether multiple Instance of `FirebaseMessagingService` are Created to Handle Multiple Data Message?
3. If One Message is being processed by `onMessageReceived()` and other message arrives will `onMessageReceived()` will trigger to handle second Message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At most a single instance of your `FirebaseMessagingService` class will exist at any one time. Its `onMessageReceived` method will be called sequentially for each message that is received. You don't need to take care of reentrancy in your code.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that there will only ever be one unique instance of the service.  If it's an Android ["started service"](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#CreatingAService), that means the service will stop after the message is handled, and Android might clean it up under memory pressure.  But it's safe to say that there will never be more than one instance at any given moment, and they will handle messages serially.

Comment: Ah right, good point. I indeed wasn't clear there. I updated to be more explicit about that.